# EasyMock migration from 1.2 to 3.4

Tags: easymock

Is there an easy way to migrate easymock 1.2 to 3.4?

I am in a situation where I cannot keep both versions in the project.
If I have both versions, I get this error:

> error: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org/easymock/internal/RecordState.>(Lorg/easymock/internal/IMocksBehavior;)V"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh dear. 1.2 is old old old. So you will need to recompile your test code using it at least. You should also remove any class extension you might have in your classpath.

From there, it should be pretty straightforward but will require a lot of find and replace. No need to have explicit control classes anymore. The only complex part is when you use default method behaviours. This was removed. So you need to replace it by stubs.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, when u said, "also remove any class extension you might have in your classpath", should i noteasymockclassextension.jar? or are you talking about any custom extension class we have written by extending "extends MockControl".

Comment: I was talking about the easymockclassextension.jar. But anything extending EasyMock 1 classes should probably be removed or rewritten.